# ; expected, .class expected -- Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that returns a power array of a given string x:

```
static public String[] powerArray( String x )
{
    String[] pArray = new String[int(Math.pow(double(2), double(x.length())))];
    pArray[0] = "";
    for (int m=1; m<pArray.length; m++) {
        for(int i=0; i<x.length(); i++) {
            for (int n=1; n<x.length(); n++) {
                for(int k=i+n; k<x.length(); k++) {
                    pArray[m] = x.substring(i, k);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return pArray;
}
```

Don't worry about the horrible for loops, I'm only asking about this bunch of errors I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/288Ck.png

If I remove the int() and double(), I get a "possible loss of precision error" in line 30

Comment: Is your code in a class?

Comment: No the function is the top level.

Comment: `int` and `double` are not methods. They're types. You can not call `int()` or `double()`. If what you want is a cast, the syntax is `(double) value` or `(int) value`.

Comment: @Firkamon You can't dump arbitrary functions in a .java file, you have to have a class. I suspect you mis-answered that question, though.

Comment: To cast to an `int`, use `(int) ...`, not `int(...)`. Same with `double`.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<x.length(); i++) {
            for (int n=1; n<x.length(); n++) {{ one issue here you should have length

Comment: @KickButtowski no. That is correct.

Comment: Java is not C++. C++ rules do not apply to Java.

Comment: I don't see 30 lines in your code snippet, so when you tell us what line the error was on, you should also point out which line is actually line 30.

Comment: @JBNizet you should read my comment with more care :)

Comment: Thank you boys! Been a while since I programmed in Java, didn't know I would falter in such an obvious statement.

Comment: @KickButtowski It was wrong before, and it still is. arrays have a `length` *attribute*. Strings have a `length()` *method*. `x` is a String.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
String[] pArray = new String[int(Math.pow(double(2), double(x.length())))];
```

You are using `int` and `Math.pow()` incorrectly. This is why you are getting all of those errors. Do this instead:

```
String[] pArray = new String[(int)Math.pow(2, x.length())];
```